# Primitive ideal space and unitary dual of a [SIN] group - when are they Hausdorff?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras, topological-groups

Recall that a locally compact group $G$ is said to be

- an $[FC]^-$ group, if each conjugacy class in $G$ has a compact closure;
- an $[SIN]$ group, if each neighborhood of the identity includes a compact neighborhood of $e$ that is invariant (as a set) under all inner automorphisms. 
  $\newcommand{\Prim}{{\rm Prim}}$

If $G$ is a locally compact $[FC]^-$ group, we know that $\Prim( C^*(G))$ is a Hausdorff space; see J.Liukkonen and R.Mosak [The primitive dual space of $[FC]^-$groups; J. Funct. Anal. 1974].

J. Peters showed that a partial converse holds. He proved that:

- if $G$ is a unimodular, amenable group whose primitive dual space $\Prim(C^*(G))$ is completely regular (under his definition), then $G$ is an $[FC]^-$ group;
- if $G$ is unimodular and $\Prim( C^*(G))$ is completely regular, then $G\in[SIN]$.

**Question**: Let $G\in[SIN]$. Under what conditions are $\Prim( C^*(G))$ or $\hat{G}$ Hausdorff spaces?

(Of course, if $G$ is abelian or compact, then $\hat{G}$ is Hausdorff).

Comment: Your title is unclear. Are you mainly interest in the primitive ideal space of the full group Cstar algebra, or the unitary dual of the algebra?

Comment: So thanks, Prof.Dr.Y.Choi for your attention. I investigate the nature of projections in full group C-star algebra.

Comment: Dear M., you haven't answered my question. The title of your question says "primitive dual space". What do you mean by these three words?

Comment: Oh,yes. For locally compact group $G$, one can define two dual space: The first, $\hat{G}$, usually called the dual space, is the set of equivalence classes of continuous irreducible unitary representations of $G$

Comment: The second, $Prim(C^*(G))$, which we might call the primitive dual space, is the set of primitive ideals of $C^*(G)$.. these spaces are closely related.

Comment: "Primitive dual space" is not standard terminology. Call it the "Primitive ideal space", because that is what it is!

Comment: OK, let us stop arguing about terminology. Presumably you have looked some of this up in sources like Dixmier's book? There, in Chapter 3, it is explained that the primitive ideal space is T_0, but if the unitary dual is T_0 then the canonical map from the p.i.space to the unitary dual is a homeomorphism.

Comment: We have $Prim (C^*(G))$= { Ker$\pi$: $\pi$$\in$ $\hat{C^*(G)}$ }. But $\hat{C^*(G)}$=$\hat{G}$, hence we can to write  $Prim (C^*(G))$= { Ker$\pi$: $\pi$$\in$ $\hat{G}$ }. Now since $Prim (C^*(G))$ denoted by $\hat{G}$, we can tell "The primitive dual space" instead to "The primitive ideal space". ( perhaps likely )

Comment: Prim Cstar(G) is NOT denoted by Ghat unless people are making a mistake. The whole point is that these two things can be different unless your group is Type I. Look, please trust me on this: "primitive ideal space" is well-established, standard terminology. "Unitary dual" (of a Cstar algebra or of a locally compact group) is also well-established terminology. Saying "Primitive dual space" just confuses the issue!

Comment: Classically, in the setting of commutative Banach algebras, people speak of the "maximal ideal space". **No one** says "maximal dual space"!

Comment: BTW, since I haven't said it yet: I think your question is an interesting one, but I currently don't have time to think about it. It might be worth sending an email to someone like Prof. E. Kaniuth who is an expert on this kind of thing.